# Android Crash in PlayStore Console

Tags: android, crash, securityexception

We found lot's of crash logs in PlayStore Console, but don't have any idea what is this about and can't reproduce it.

```
java.lang.SecurityException: 
  at android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:1689)
  at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel (DatabaseUtils.java:183)
  at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel (DatabaseUtils.java:135)
  at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.insert (ContentProviderNative.java:482)
  at android.content.ContentResolver.insert (ContentResolver.java:1279)
  at android.content.AsyncQueryHandler$WorkerHandler.handleMessage (AsyncQueryHandler.java:96)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:241)
  at android.os.HandlerThread.run (HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Looks like the exception doesn't depend on any Android version ( at least it happened for 7.1, 7.0, 6.0, 5.1 versions), but as you can see from the screenshot all listed devices are Sony devices

[image: Here is screenshot from crash description page in Console.]

Do you have any guess what this can be related to?

Comment: it would be very helpful to know the context of what your app does or how it might be related to the exception.

Comment: Hi Chisko. Well I am not sure that it will help but the app is a game.

Answer (score 2):

We found a cause of exception.

The exception indeed was Sony specific and was related to notifications.

Here is full stacktrace.

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Missing permission to insert badges
11-14 19:41:50.414: E/DatabaseUtils(1389):  at com.sonymobile.home.resourceprovider.HomeResourceProvider.insertBadge(HomeResourceProvider.java:113)
11-14 19:41:50.414: E/DatabaseUtils(1389):  at com.sonymobile.home.resourceprovider.HomeResourceProvider.insert(HomeResourceProvider.java:58)
11-14 19:41:50.414: E/DatabaseUtils(1389):  at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.insert(ContentProvider.java:220)
11-14 19:41:50.414: E/DatabaseUtils(1389):  at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:167)
11-14 19:41:50.414: E/DatabaseUtils(1389):  at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
11-14 19:41:50.414: E/DatabaseUtils(1389):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
11-14 19:41:50.414: W/dalvikvm(28623): threadid=20: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x415b8d88)
11-14 19:41:50.414: E/AndroidRuntime(28623): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncQueryWorker
11-14 19:41:50.414: E/AndroidRuntime(28623): Process: air.com.plexonic.meln2, PID: 28623
11-14 19:41:50.414: E/AndroidRuntime(28623): java.lang.SecurityException: Missing permission to insert badges
11-14 19:41:50.414: E/AndroidRuntime(28623):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1474)
11-14 19:41:50.414: E/AndroidRuntime(28623):    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:185)
11-14 19:41:50.414: E/AndroidRuntime(28623):    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:137)
11-14 19:41:50.414: E/AndroidRuntime(28623):    at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.insert(ContentProviderNative.java:479)
11-14 19:41:50.414: E/AndroidRuntime(28623):    at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:1196)
11-14 19:41:50.414: E/AndroidRuntime(28623):    at android.content.AsyncQueryHandler$WorkerHandler.handleMessage(AsyncQueryHandler.java:96)
11-14 19:41:50.414: E/AndroidRuntime(28623):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-14 19:41:50.414: E/AndroidRuntime(28623):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
11-14 19:41:50.414: E/AndroidRuntime(28623):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Solution was to add specific Sony permissions to the AndroidManifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.sonyericsson.home.permission.BROADCAST_BADGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.sonymobile.home.permission.PROVIDER_INSERT_BADGE"/>
```